# CUDA driver compatibility with nvfortran compiler from nvidia hpc sdk 20.7

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have installed the nvidia compilers (nvcc, nvfortran). I downloaded it from the [NVIDIA HPC SDK v20.7 site](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-hpc-sdk-download). I then compiled non-cuda codes with nvfortran, and it works fine. But when i compile the first cuda-based example from [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/index.html), it throws the error:

```
nvcc-Error-CUDA version 8.0 was not installed with this HPC SDK: /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.7/cuda/8.0/bin
```

I then ran `nvidia-smi` and got

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K600         Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 25%   46C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    589MiB /   973MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

So my NVIDIA driver version is 375.66. And according to cuda toolkit compatibility info given in [table 1](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html) of the cuda toolkit page, the cuda 8.0 (or lower) toolkit is required for this driver version.

**So my questions are -**

(1) Do Linux systems with NVIDIA GPU devices come preinstalled with CUDA toolkits? Following [these steps](https://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/gpu/nvidia/verify_cuda_install.html) to check if CUDA is installed or not, I opened the `/usr/local` folder but there wanst any `cudaX.Y` folder.

(2) Given that I have this version of NVIDIA driver, should I go ahead and download cuda8.0? If I do, then the nv compilers that installed with the HPC SDK v20.7 may still not work - according to sec 3.2 in the [install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/hpc-sdk-release-notes/index.html), stand-alone support for cuda10.1,10.2 and 11 is provided. Does this mean it wont support CUDA8.0? If so, should I download a new driver?

(3) I just want to start off with GPU programming, so is this possible with the driver that I have? Im ok with any compiler. Will pg compilers work?

**Some more info reg my system -**

shell command `nvfortran --version`:

```
nvfortran 20.7-0 LLVM 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge 
NVIDIA Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2020, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
```

shell command `pgfortran --version`:

```
pgfortran (aka nvfortran) 20.7-0 LLVM 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge 
PGI Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2020, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
```

shell command `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.66  Mon May  1 15:29:16 PDT 2017
GCC version:  gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to solve your immediate problem, you need to find or install a CUDA environment that's compatible with your drivers, and then make sure the `CUDA_HOME` environment variable is pointing to the root of this environment, and retry your build.

My expertise is not in Fortran, but I have just worked through a related case for a user at my facility. In my case, the system has CUDA 9.1 installed separately from the NVidia HPC SDK, and also the SDK version 20.9, bundled with CUDA 10.1, 10.2, and 11.0, and the system has the version 418 NVidia drivers, which will work with CUDA 10.1, but not 10.2 or 11.0.

In my case, the `nvfortran` command will not build against our CUDA 9.1, which is in /usr/local/cuda.

But, we can build things by setting `CUDA_HOME=/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.9/cuda/10.1` and re-running the `nvfortran` command.

Additional care is required to ensure you link against the right Cuda libraries, many of which are (in my case) in `/opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/20.9/math_libs/10.1/lib64`.

For your case, if version 20.7 of the HPC SDK is bundled with CUDA 8.0, then setting `CUDA_HOME` correctly is probably all you need to do.

It's possible, though, that version 20.7 of the SDK is not compatible with older versions of CUDA, and you might need a newer CUDA, and newer drivers, before `nvfortran` will work.

To elaborate slightly on some of your other concerns, NVidia-equipped Linux systems generally do not come with CUDA tools pre-installed, although I think some vendors do this. As with most things Linux, the detailed answers depend to some degree on your system configuration, and the right combination of paths and environment variables will often get you where you want to go.

If you're just getting started, you may want to skip the HPC SDK and start with native CUDA. It's lower level, and may not be Fortran-friendly, but you can get a working environment with probably a single CUDA install.